# Recommend an application that maps the menu architecture of a desktop/enterprise application

Tags: usability, gui-design, desktop-application, information

I want to map all the GUI menus in an application. For example, in Firefox: "New Tab > Open File > Open File dialog.

Is there an application that can map this by analyzing the executable or code? Or will this be a manual process?

I'm probably not invoking the best keywords to search for such an application.

Comment: Sadly, this is a manual process.  What's your goal in doing this?

Comment: If it's that complex of a UI where manually doing it is daunting, maybe it's time to scrap it all and start fresh. :)

Comment: My goal is to display (in a flat map) usability issues to our developer teams, in the hopes of revamping our UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try searching for "Accessibility API", "UI Automation" or looking at [Microsoft UI Automation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_UI_Automation).  These types of tools allow you to access and even invoke menus and other UI elements in another application.

Screen readers, screen magnifiers and such use this technique to make computers more accessible for the visually impaired and those with other disabilities.

And you can use the same technique to scrape menu structures of another application if you have a bit of programming skill.